# How to prefix the first 3 lines of a file with different variables?

Tags: linux, batch, sed, awk, string

So I have to go through a log I am emailed (in windows), search for a line to determine the models serial number, I figured an easy way to do that was to write up an ugly batch script to convert the .msg so I can read the file. example:

```
cat "*Pre*.msg" | strings2 > agrep.txt
cat agrep.txt | grep "D24" > a21s.txt
cat a21s.txt | cut -d" " -f7 > Air21Serials.txt
```

that leaves me with 3 unique numbers, how do would I add ALPHA to line 1, BETA to line2 and GAMMA to line 3 with a space or a : as a delimiter?

---

**Update:** the file `a21s.txt` is similar to

```
0 1 BXP_0 AIR21B4AB2P KRC118046/1 R3B D240090254 20140416 
0 1 BXP_1 AIR21B4AB2P KRC118046/1 R3B D240088108 20140414 
0 1 BXP_2 AIR21B4AB2P KRC118046/1 R3B D240090208 20140414
```

Comment: In which posiyion is D24? Is it in a fixed coulumn? If you provide some lines like the input you have and the desired output it will be more simple to understand you :)  Btw if you have `awk` you can do it (to filter and add strings) with one command.

Comment: C:\-----------\AIR32\MAHON>cat "*Pre*.msg" | strings2 > agrep.txt
C:\-----------\AIR32\MAHON>cat agrep.txt | grep "D24" > a21s.txt

C:\-----------\AIR32\MAHON>more a21s.txt
0 1 BXP_0 AIR21B4AB2P KRC118046/1 R3B D240090254 20140416
0 1 BXP_1 AIR21B4AB2P KRC118046/1 R3B D240088108 20140414
0 1 BXP_2 AIR21B4AB2P KRC118046/1 R3B D240090208 20140414

C:\-----------\AIR32\MAHON>cat a21s.txt
0 1 BXP_0 AIR21B4AB2P KRC118046/1 R3B D240090254 20140416
0 1 BXP_1 AIR21B4AB2P KRC118046/1 R3B D240088108 20140414
0 1 BXP_2 AIR21B4AB2P KRC118046/1 R3B D240090208 20140414

Comment: Hi Jon,wecome on superuser. Please [edit] your own post so that it will be more undestandable and you wll have no limit of characters... reading the comment from a mobile it's more challenging then the Sunday puzzle ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many way to do what you are searching for, just a couple of examples.

#### `awk`  and a tailored solution

One solution tailored  on you example is to use `awk` and pass 3 variables to it. It is not general because if you will have 4 lines you have to pass 4 variables and so on...

The `awk` command has the simple way to manage the column through their number (`$1`,`$2`...`$NF` the last one).

- Just to keep it more simple to read here I use your old intermediate file `a21s.txt`

  ```
  awk -v s1="ALPHA" -v s2="BETA" -v s3="GAMMA" '
    NR==1 {print s1,$7} ;  
    NR==2 {print s2,$7} ;  
    NR==3 {print s3,$7} ; '   a21s.txt
  ```

  - In the first line you pass 3 variable to `awk` with the option `-v`.
  - In the following lines you use that the internal variable *NR*, keeps count of the number of the line. So you go to print the variable *s1*, only when you have the first line, the *s2* with the second ... and so on.
  - In the last line after the `'` you can specify the file name so you needn't to call the `cat` process and to pipe it to the `awk` one.
  - If the variable (ALPHA,BETA...) are generable with some mechanism (e.g. "Serial01, Serial02") you can put it instead of the controls on the line number and the external variable.
- **Practical note:** under *nix you can to *trains of commands* piping (`|`) one output to the following with no need to create intermediate files.
  So in you example you could use directly:

  ```
  cat "*Pre*.msg" | strings2 | grep "D24" | cut -d" " -f7 > Air21Serials.txt
  ```

  Instead of `cut` in this case you can use the `awk` command, `cat "*Pre*.msg" | strings2 | grep "D24" | awk '...' > final_file.txt`.

#### A more general solution: `paste` + `awk`

Let's say you have your `a21s.txt` file and another one (`b.txt`) with the same number of lines and within the strings (one word each) that you want to prefix (as the following).

```
ALPHA
BETA
GAMMA
```

you can simply use

```
paste b.txt a21.txt | awk '{print $1,$8}' >  Air21Serials.txt
```

Note that now the column of your serial il the 8th because you add another one before with paste.

---

**Note**

ask to Linux itself for more information with `man awk` and `man paste` `:-)`

Comment: that worked out great, the paste option did anyways.  thank you

Comment: You're welcome. Just a memo for the next time: when you go to ask for a problem, that problem is extremely clean to you (you faced off, you tried to resolve...) but it is unknown to the people that will read the question. Try to find a clean and brief way to expose the problem in order to simplify the work of the answering people. `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

echo ALPHA **>** agrep.txt ; cat "*Pre*.msg" | strings2 **>>** agrep.txt

that may not be the exact line .. the concept is, that you *first* want to put the word "Alpha" into the file .. using a > symbol creates the file, and using a >> appends to the file.  Without a "newline" it should put the word ALPHA in there and then append the first message.

you may need to play a bit to get the code working exactly.

EDIT:
Searching found using **cat** and **printf** are better options rather than echo, as echo may be different depending on OS

eg: cat ("ALPHA: ") > agrep.txt ; cat "*Pre*.msg" | strings2 **>>** agrep.txt

And for doing a "one liner" command the first pipe should've been a ; or &&

; in-between commands always executes the next command 
&& between commands executes the next command only if the previous succeeded 
and 
|| (double pipe) executes the next command only if the previous failed

Comment: good start to an idea but when i grep "D24*" > change that to >>its just going to make new lines won't it?

Comment: I've seen times when it does, and times when it doesn't.  Doing additional searches found the same and the recommendation was to use printf instead as you could literally add a newline or not. (editing the above)  PS. I'm in the middle of updating my vmware workstation and adding a linux vm to test with.

Comment: also could use CAT on a string and that won't produce the newlines.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `strings2` does or what your input looks like so, I can't be 100% sure this will work as expected. But maybe it will at least point you in the right direction. `cat` can accept input from stdin. So, you could also do

```
echo ALPHA: | cat - "*Pre*.msg" | strings2 > agrep.txt
echo BETA: | cat - agrep.txt | grep "D24" > a21s.txt
echo GAMMA: | cat - a21s.txt | cut -d" " -f7 > Air21Serials.txt
```

Comment: strings2 is advanced copy of strings for windows  --- its essentially stripping a binary file of ascii and unicode strings.